# Show hidden div above a just clicked div

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I have 3 divs. When I click one of them, the div will disappear and a greeting div will appear. Got this all working, please see my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mauricederegt/pknpb/1/

At the moment this greetings div appears at a fixed position. How to make it so that it will appear above the div that was just clicked?

Is this even possible at all?

Hope someone can help me out

Thank you for your time

(ps also why are the divs forced down when clicked?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3 divs drop down because `.greetings` has relative positioning. If you make it absolute and get the offset of the clicked element, you can position it exactly above that element and without it changing the layout of the other divs:

```
var offset = $(this).hide(500).offset();
var score = 'Hello';
$('.greet').text(score);

$('.greet')
      .show()
      .css({
          top: offset.top - $('.greet').height(),
          left: offset.length,
          opacity: 1,
      })
      .stop()
      .delay(200)  
      .animate({top: 20, opacity: 0},1000);
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orig/42pZZ/2/)

Comment: I think I didn't understood the question :P. +1!

Comment: @ori Thanks this works great, small request: what if I want to show it a bit higher of the div instead of right on top of it?

Comment: I would too :-)  `top: offset.top - $('.greet').height() - 20` (or any number that suits you)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting each 'Hint' in a container with it's message:

```
<div class="hint-container">
  <div class="hint"> HINT! </div>
  <div class="greet"> Greetings </div>
</div>
```

the give the container a fixed size and relative position:

```
.hint-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

The you can give an absolute position to the containers, make them occupy all the container and hide one of them:

```
.hint-container > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
 }
 .hint-container .greet {
   display: none;
 }
```

From here you can go on as you where doing ^.^

I hope it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am not versed enough to give the code in jquery for this. But, I believe you would have to send in the click event to the method handling the div with class greet. And then with position absolute set the left and top of the class greet div to the top and left stored in the event.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the element's position relative to it's container using the .position(), or it's offset relative to the document using .offset().

in this case, it might look something like this:

```
$('.ht').click(function hint() {
    var x = $(this).offset().left;//get offset relative to document
    $(this).hide(500);
    score = 'Hello';
      $('.greet').text(score);

    $('.greet')
          .hide()
          .css({
              bottom: 20,
              left: x, //add x variable here
              opacity: 1,
          })
          .show()
          .stop()
          .delay(200)  
          .animate({'bottom':75, opacity: 0},1000);
});
```

however you'd probably want to make the .greet class position:absolute, and you might have to do something with the height.